# How to authorize with client credential flow and password flow using opendidict?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, openiddict

I am using opendiddict on net core 3 and to protect my API I was using password flow and doing the authorization process with roles. Now I need to add client credential flow for the same API and I do not know how to do it.Here are my methos in the API:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Rol_A,Rol_B", AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
 [HttpGet("message")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetMessage_A()
 {...}

 [Authorize(Roles = "Rol_C,Rol_B", AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
 [HttpGet("message")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetMessage_B()
 {...}
```

But Applications does not have roles. I was reading about using scopes to protect the API but I do not understand how to associate the user and applications with the scopes. On the other hand I tried too, with policies but one method must be decorated with no more than one policy at a time,so if I have multiples combinations of roles it is a mess. I have this anyway:

In startup.cs

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Policy_A", policy =>
            {
                policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                {
                    //how to evaluate if application has permission

                    if (context.User.HasClaim(x => x.Type == OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role && (x.Value == "Rol_A" || x.Value == "Rol_B")))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
         });
```

I create my applications with this code:

```
  var descriptor = new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
  {
    ClientId = "console",
    ClientSecret = "388D45FA-B36B-4988-BA59-B187D329C207",
    DisplayName = "My client application",
    Permissions =
    {
      OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
      OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
      OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Prefixes.Scope+"api1"
    }
  };

  await manager.CreateAsync(descriptor);
```

so my questions are:

1. Does it make sense what I try to do?
2. How can I add the permissions that I gave to the descriptor to the token, so it can be use to check in the policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, add all the claims you need in the authentication ticket when handling the token request. To distinguish applications and users, you can add a custom claim indicating whether the token represents an application or a user.

For more information on how to add claims, take a look at the client credentials flow sample: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/ClientCredentialsFlow/AuthorizationServer/Controllers/AuthorizationController.cs

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thanks you!  Is it something wrong if I use password flow for machine-to-machine ?

Comment: Hey. Technically, it's something you could do. Would I recommend it? Definitely not: simply use the client credentials flow for machine-to-machine, it's been designed for this exact purpose.